# Internet Protocall addressing conflict

Tags: ip

Internet Protocall Address 1--192.168.32.1/16. 
Internet Protocall Address 2--192.168.32.1/24.
Are these Internet Protocall addresses are same or different?

Comment: They are same ip address, but the machines with that address may be different machines. IP address of 192.168.0.0/16 (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255) are assigned for private address by RFC1918. These addresses are used for privately (can not be used as unique ip address on the Internet), so many machines has same ip adress but that does not make trouble, because they never communicate another on othre network segment.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. Only Subnet mask is different. So IP Address1 is in bigger subnet then IP address2. Both of them cant co-exist in same subnet, since it will lead to a conflict.